# Generating complimentary hex color of randomly generated hex color in JS?

Tags: javascript, random, colors, hex

From what I understand you can get the complimentary color of a given hex color by subtracting the known color from white (#FFFFFF). In my case, the known color is one that I am randomly generating using the following code:

```
var randomColor = "#000000".replace(/0/g,function(){
return (~~(Math.random()*16)).toString(16);});
```

And I basically want to do this:

```
function compColor(randomColor){
    return 0xFFFFFF - randomColor;
}
```

I have this random hex number but I'm unable to subtract it from a decimal. Will I have to convert from hex to decimal and back to hex again to get the complimentary color I'm looking for? It seems like this is not the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend that you keep your colours as numbers, thereby making generation of the complementary colour a simple mathematical operation.

Only when required should you convert those colours to hexadecimal format, or indeed any other string format, such as `rgb(r, g, b)`

One option would be a single 24-bit integer, with red in the topmost 8 bits, then green, and blue in the least significant bits:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x1000000);
}

function getComplementColor(c) {
    return 0xffffff - c;
}

function getHexColor(c) {
    return '#' + ("000000" + c.toString(16)).substr(-6);
}
```

[The concatenation and `substr` call in the `getHexColor()` function is a neat way of padding out the hex number with leading zeroes]